# React: updating controlled child component

Tags: reactjs, user-interface

I'm trying to create some React components using TypeScript, one of which handles user input (let's call it `MyCtrl`), and the other reacting to this user input and updating the backend (`MyUpdatingCtrl`), both being controlled components. My issue is that when updating the backend fails I need to revert the value in the user input component, but since it keeps the value in its state I can't update it from the outer component. So how do I handle this case correctly?

Note that I simplified my situation to explain my issue more easily. The following bit of code does not represent my actual project, but illustrates the issue in the simplest way I could think of.

MyCtrl:

```
export interface MyCtrlProps {
    Value: string;
    OnValueChanged: (newValue: string) => void;
}

interface MyCtrlState {
    CurrentValue: string;
}

export class MyCtrl extends React.Component<MyCtrlProps, MyCtrlState>{
    constructor(props: MyCtrlProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { CurrentValue: props.Value };
    }

    render() {
        return <input onChange={this.onInputChanged} value={this.state.CurrentValue} />;
    }

    private onInputChanged = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
        this.setState({ ...this.state, CurrentValue: e.target.value },
            () => this.props.OnValueChanged(this.state.CurrentValue));
    };
}
```

MyUpdatingCtrl:

```
export interface MyUpdatingCtrlProps {
    Value: string;
}

interface MyUpdatingCtrlState {
    CurrentValue: string;
    PreviousValue: string;
}

export class MyUpdatingCtrl extends React.Component<MyUpdatingCtrlProps, MyUpdatingCtrlState>{
    constructor(props: MyUpdatingCtrlProps) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            CurrentValue: props.Value,
            PreviousValue: props.Value
        };
    }

    render() {
        return <MyCtrl Value={this.state.CurrentValue} OnValueChanged={this.onValueChanged} />
    }

    private onValueChanged = (newValue: string): void => {
        try {
            // update backend
        }
        catch (error) {
            // How do I reset the value of MyCtrl to the previous value here?
        }
    };
}
```

Setting the state.CurrentValue in the catch block inside MyUpdatingCtrl.onValueChanged of course won't update the value in MyCtrl, so what should I do?

Answer (score -1):

first of all, you can't get the updated state like that, use

```
this.props.OnValueChanged(e.target.value);
```

because **setState** is an async function and can't get its updated value in the function you are calling it except by using the callback method

Comment: As I said, this is not the actual project code so that doesn't matter, and your answer does not address my issue at all.